# How to configure a "Connected Rigid Body" in a DistanceJoint2D inside a C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a swing mechanism which could swing around a fixed pivot (a `GameOject`) which has a kinematic rigidbody. The objective is to use `DistanceJoint2D` for the swing mechanism.

But the problem I am facing is to Set and Change the "Connected Rigid Body" inside the script. Is there a way out for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: The [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DistanceJoint2D.html) is always your friend ;) There you can find that the property is called [connectedBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint2D-connectedBody.html)

Comment: Given that this was answerable, and quite easy to understand that the OP had a terminology knowledge gap due to Unity's naming 'conventions' and documentation, combined with a clear and concise question about how to connect to a joint, which was very clearly answered, can this question be taken out of hold and made back into a useful question and answer for others?

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Connected Rigid Body" in the Editor but the property name in scripting is "connectedBody". Simply assign a Rigidbody2D reference to it.

```
public DistanceJoint2D distanceJoint2D;
public Rigidbody2D rb2D;

void Start()
{
    distanceJoint2D.connectedBody = rb2D;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Thanks for your time and assistance :)